# Navigation Drawer from Bottom with horizontal scrollbar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, horizontalscrollview

i'm trying to implement a menu which i want on the bottom outside of the screen. When i swipe up from the bottom edge of the screen i want it to appear there.
Furthermore i want a `HorzizontalScrollView` in there. Actually it should work like a `Navigation Drawer` on the side.

Here is the layout I already tried. I used the umano AndroidSlidingUpPanel:

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
sothree:panelHeight="200dp"
sothree:shadowHeight="4dp"
sothree:overlay="true">

<TextView
    android:text="Hier wird das pdf gezeigt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"/>


    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/file_scroll_view"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/file_scroll_view_linear_layout"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

The slide up works, but i don
t know how to position it outside of the screen and how to let it only slide up until it aligns the bottom edge.

Furthermore I want the `ScrollView` working. Before I tried with the `SldingUpPanel` it worked like charm but now its not scrollable.

Anyone got an idea or any hint how to solve this?

Comment: there's a library for that: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Comment: This is what i used ;) and it does not work the way I need it. I don't want anything of the menu to be seen before it is dragged in and i dont want it to slide the whole way up but instead stay at the bottom of the screen...

Answer (score 1):

for nothing to be seen you have to:

```
slidePanel.setPanelHeight(0); // I couldn't find anything on XML for that
```

and for it to stop midway through:

```
slidePanel.expandPane(0.1f); // for example for 10% of screen.
```

Comment: Okay, is slidePanel then my second element in the layout, so my HorizontalScrollView?